# How to avoid UICollectionView repeating cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello I have a `UICollectionView`. I load data from a `NSMutableArray` and it has 2 objects. But my problem is its repeating the same cells again.

I am using `XIB` Files, and swift code, Can any one help me....

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (contentImagesLsit?.count)!
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "GridCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GridCell
    print((contentImagesLsit?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? StylistMedia)!.imageURl)
    cell.imageCell?.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: (contentImagesLsit?.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? StylistMedia)!.imageURl), placeholderImage: nil, usingActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)

    return cell
}
```

Here is my simulator Output

[image]

Comment: Don't register nib in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. Are `contentImageLsit` objects different?

Comment: @venky Siddani Please check your array data . may be you fill up same data twice . Thanks

Comment: No, Data is correct, its came from DataBase

Comment: Can any one send me the code or tutorial , if you are using UICOLLECTION VIEW  with XIB files